# How to receive data when event Activity_Pause occure

Tags: android, basic4android

I am making an Android APP that connect to my server (VB6), everything is working perfect, but I have a small problem
I want the APP stay able to receive data even when the Activity_pause occure
I notice that the APP will receive the data when the user resume the application

its something like viber, the program is able to receive events even when the UI is not loaded 
how  :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to implement a `Service` to receive message on background when your Activity is onPause.

Here's the [Reference -- Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Thanks alot, I will check this soon, Note that I am using Basic4Android. I hope the concept will be the same